# Python pandas dataframe read from_records, "AssertionError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 22 columns"

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a list where `a` is `806` in length. I want to import to a dataframe where the first item in the list is the column name. My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
b = pd.DataFrame.from_records(a[1:],columns=[a[0]])
```

this gives me an error of `AssertionError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 22 columns` while clearly i have only one column.

I've tried a representation of the code and it works. So I'm not sure what is going on here. Here is a representation of the code:

```
import pandas as pd
arr= ['title', 'a','b','','','']
arr= filter(None, arr)
b = pd.DataFrame.from_records(arr[1:],columns=[arr[0]] )
```

Must be something wrong with my list? I printed out `a` and it looks fine, like a regular list. I have pasted the printed output of `a` and placed that as the variable `list`, and it gives me the same error `AssertionError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 22 columns`. Seems like something wrong with my list. What else can I do to debug?

Edit (based on DSM suggestion):

```
import pandas as pd
arr=['Title', '000660.ks']
b = pd.DataFrame.from_records(arr[1:],columns=[arr[0]] )
```

This gives `AssertionError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 8 columns`

Comment: Rather than telling us about the problem, show it to us: edit your question to give an example we can copy and paste.  First, find the minimal failing case.  Does it still fail for `a[1:400]`?  For `a[1:100]`? `a[1:5]`?  Note that if you have data in the list you can't show us, then replace the strings by "A" and floats by 1.0, etc., until you come up with an example you *can* post.

Comment: Great suggestion. I've tried your suggestion and will repost code.

Comment: First, don't use `list` as a variable name, let's say your array is named `arr`, try `pd.DataFrame([arr[1:]],columns=[arr[0]])`

Comment: @mtadd. Thanks for the suggestion. Edits made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `from_records` you want to use the default DataFrame constructor.

`from_records` expects a list of something iterable, so for example, the string `'0006660.ks'` is being read in as `('0','0',... ,'s')` which is why you are getting an error about 8 columns in the data.

```
b = pd.DataFrame(a[1:], columns=[a[0]])
```