# finding all regex matches from a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

i am trying to extract some data from a dataframe, however following query only extract the first match and ignores the rest of the matches, for example if the entire data is:

```
df['value']=
           0   123 blah blah blah, 456 blah blah blah, 129kfj blah blah
           1   237 blah blah blah, 438 blah blah blah, 365kfj blah blah 
           ...
```

and the regex is:

```
df['newCol']=df['value'].str.extract("[0-9]{3}")
```

i want the result to be a new column name "newCol" as:

```
newCol
------
123,456,129
237,438,365
...
```

but the actual result i get is only the first number:

```
newCol
------
123
237
```

what is wrong here? :(

thank you

**UPDATE:**

thanks to MaxU I found the solution, just couple of suggestions. I had Pandas 0.18.1 so extractall didn't work for me untill i updated pandas to 0.19, so remember to check your pandas version if you have issue with Extractall...second, apply(','.join) didn't work for me because I had some non string values (Null values) and it couldn't handle it so I used Lambda and it finally worked with a small modification of MaxU solution.

```
x['value'].str.extractall(r'(\d{3})').unstack().apply(lambda x:','.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
```

Comment: `extract` returns the first match only. You want [`extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html#pandas.Series.str.extractall). See MaxU's answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use [Series.str.extractall()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) method:

```
In [57]: x
Out[57]:
                                                    value
0  123 blah blah blah 456 blah blah blah 129kfj blah blah
1  237 blah blah blah 438 blah blah blah 365kfj blah blah

In [58]: x['newCol'] = x['value'].str.extractall(r'(\d{3})').unstack().apply(','.join, 1)

In [59]: x
Out[59]:
                                                    value       newCol
0  123 blah blah blah 456 blah blah blah 129kfj blah blah  123,456,129
1  237 blah blah blah 438 blah blah blah 365kfj blah blah  237,438,365
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [77]: x
Out[77]:
                                                      value
0  123 blah blah blah, 456 blah blah blah, 129kfj blah blah
1  237 blah blah blah, 438 blah blah blah, 365kfj blah blah

In [78]: x['value'].str.extractall(r'(\d{3})').unstack().apply(','.join, 1)
Out[78]:
0    123,456,129
1    237,438,365
dtype: object
```

Comment: now i', getting this error: AssertionError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 6 columns...reading this(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145140/python-pandas-dataframe-read-from-records-assertionerror-1-columns-passed-pa)  i think it's looking at "129kfj" as 1,2,9,k,f,j but i don't understand why

Comment: @Faranak, I can't reproduce this error... Can you try it step by step in order to see which part produces this error: `x['value'].str.extractall(r'(\d{3})')`, `x['value'].str.extractall(r'(\d{3})').unstack()`, etc.

Comment: i just changed extract to extractall and it produce this error: df['value'].str.extractall("[0-9]{3}")

Comment: but it's not my solution, it's yours... ;-) Try it with my RegEx

Comment: lol i ran this: x['value'].str.extractall(r'(\d{3})') still same error: 1 columns passed, passed data had 3 columns

Comment: @Faranak, i'm afraid i'd need a __reproducible__ data set in order to debug it...

Comment: @Faranak, does it give you this error when you simply execute this: `df['value'].str.extractall(r'(\d{3})')` __without__ assigning it to a new column?

Comment: yes it does, the only different between actual data and the example data that i can see is there are "," between sentenses, for example: "123 blah blah blah, 456 blah blah blah, 129kfj blah blah"...can it be the issue?

Comment: @Faranak, no, comas, shouldn't play any role - see UPDATE

Comment: @Faranak, what is your Pandas version? A few bugs of `.str.extractall()` have been fixed in Pandas 0.19.2

Comment: pandas version is  0.18.1...ahh ok i'm, updating it now, hopefully it works :(

Comment: you're right, i upgraded Pandas now if I run this it works without error: df['value'].str.extractall(r'(\d{3})')...however when i add .unstack().apply(','.join, 1) this is the error i get: TypeError: ('sequence item 1: expected str instance, NoneType found', 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: ok i got it, finally lol...i just updated your solution with: x['value'].str.extractall(r'(\d{3})').unstack().apply(lambda x:','.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)

Comment: by the way, if you ever check this comments (lol) how can i get rid of duplicates here? for example if i have two "123" in first row (index 0), how can i have only one "123" instead of ("123,123")?