# How to use two regex capture groups to make two pandas columns

Tags: regex, pandas

I have a dataframe column of strings and I want to extract numbers to another column:

```
    column
    1 abc123
    2 def456
    3 ghi789jkl012
```

I've used:

```
dataframe["newColumn"] = dataframe["column"].str.extract("(\d*\.?\d+)", expand=True)
```

It works, but only captures the first block of numbers to one column. My desired output is

```
column           newColumn  newColumn2
1 abc123         123        NaN
2 def456         456        NaN
3 ghi789jkl012   789        012
```

but can't figure out how to do it

Comment: `extract` only finds the first match, use `extractall` or `findall`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew - I think here is closed incorrect., part time dupe.

Comment: @jezrael Check now, this is the right duplicate reason.

Comment: Wrong dupe, reopened.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I am looked for it, but cannot find it. Maybe you have more luck.

Comment: **Duplicate of [finding all regex matches from a pandas dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42379389/finding-all-regex-matches-from-a-pandas-dataframe-column)**.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew agree that is the correct dupe

Comment: @Manakin - missing selecting column `0`, missing `add_prefix`, missing `join`... So partly dupe too. Also no `.apply(','.join, 1)` is possible use here. Or not?

Comment: @jezrael that was his desired output but I think his initial and main quesiton is the use of `extractall` ? your choice but personally I feel its a dupe

Comment: @Manakin - hmmm, is possible post my answer to dupe answer and should be accepted? Never, because it si partly dupe. So I think it is partly dupe by `extractall`, but not dupe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html), last add to original DataFrame by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = dataframe.join(dataframe["column"].str.extractall("(\d*\.?\d+)")[0]
                                       .unstack()
                                       .add_prefix('newColumn'))
print (df)
         column newColumn0 newColumn1
1        abc123        123        NaN
2        def456        456        NaN
3  ghi789jkl012        789        012
```

Or you can use `(\d+)`, thank you @Manakin:

```
df = (dataframe.join(dataframe["column"].str.extractall("(\d+)")[0]
                                        .unstack()
                                        .add_prefix('newColumn'))
print (df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also use split, expand=True and join back to df.

```
df.join(df.column.str.split('\D+', expand=True).replace({None: np.NaN}).rename({2:'newColumn2',1:'newColumn'},axis=1).iloc[:,-2::])


 

    column newColumn newColumn2
1        abc123       123        NaN
2        def456       456        NaN
3  ghi789jkl012       789        012
```