# How do I handle regex and null values inside a lambda expression?

Tags: python, pandas, null, nan, python-re

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":['1324 cats',pd.np.nan,'There were 25647900 tickets',34254], "B":[543,678678,0,0]})
```

In an example DataFrame, like the one above, I am trying to calculate a new column where I extract any consecutive runs of numbers.  I'm treating the cell value as a string when I hand it to re.search() in cases where there's only an integer in the cell, and I'm attempting to use pd.isna() to bypass null values, but I still get the following error: "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"

`df['C'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: re.search(r'\d+',str(x))[0] if not pd.isna(x) else x)`

This approach works fine when not involving re in the process, like this:

`df['C'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: 'Y' if not pd.isna(x) else x)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try convert the column into string type, then use `str.extract` (which is equivalent to `re.search`):

```
df['A'].astype(str).str.extract('(\d+)')
```

Output:

```
          0
0      1324
1       NaN
2  25647900
3     34254
```

**Note**: Your code would work fine if every single row contains a capture (some digits). `re.search` returns `None` when the pattern isn't found, so `re.search(...)[0]` fails and triggers that error.

Comment: Thanks, curious, will this work like re.search if there are multiple runs of digits? i.e., "There were 452 months with 14 inches of rain" to yield the 452 and 14?

Comment: `.str.extractall` instead of `.str.extract`.

Comment: Thanks, combined with the unstack and null handling from this post I think this gets me unstuck. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42379389/finding-all-regex-matches-from-a-pandas-dataframe-column  Would still be interested in seeing how to conditionally handle using re in the lambdas for cases where it didn't find any matches